# WP7 app to read content from a website without RSS feeds

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, web, rss

i have to develop a minimalistic and simple windows phone 7/7.1 app for my college website for displaying new notices and and any new content in the students' section . The website has a separate page for notices and  a separate page for study material download. The site has no rss feeds. Please help me figure out how can i read the data into my app and display it on the app.

the website is www.niecdelhi.ac.in
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

When a site doesn't publicly expose data in a machine readable format, you can scrape the HTML and extract the data yourself. This is a tedious and error-prone process, not to mention that changing the site design will immediately break your code.

To scrape a site, use a library that can access the HTML. For example, you can use [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to extract data from HTML and then use it for whatever purpose you want.

You can also create a web service that will periodically perform data extraction and you can then publish RSS feed from your own service. This way your mobile applications don't depend on the parsing code which you can always tweak and update.